# TEIID Spring boot integration with two sql server. QueryParserException

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, teiid

I am getting below error when trying to fetch data from two different mssql servers:

> TEIID31100 Parsing error: Encountered "SELECT id, [*]parameter[*],
> value" at line 9, column 12. Was expecting: "char" | "date" | "time" |
> "timestamp" | "cast" | "convert" | "any" | "array" | "array_agg" |
> "case" ...    at
> org.teiid.query.parser.QueryParser.convertParserException(QueryParser.java:231)
> ~[teiid-engine-16.0.0.jar:16.0.0]     ... 28 common frames omitted

My Class:

```
 @SelectQuery("SELECT id, parameter, value, created_date FROM database63.DAC_SYS_MEMORY"
         + " UNION ALL"
         + " SELECT id, parameter, value, created_date FROM database54.DAC_SYS_MEMORY")
 public class CustomRecord {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="Parameter")
    private String parameter;
    @Column(name="Value")
    private String value;
    @Column(name="created_date")
    private Date createdDate;
```

I have integrated Teiid spring boot and been trying to fetch data from two diff sqlservers

Comment: i would make a guess that this teiid thing doesn't handle UNIONs in query, seems it wants to parse the query manually and fails

Comment: @siggemannen, as per the documentation(https://github.com/teiid/teiid-spring-boot/blob/master/docs/UserGuide.adoc) it supports.

Comment: @ramesh-reddy kindly, can you help me out here ?

Comment: aha, i think "parameter" is a reserved word in their parser. So you should use another column name. Also, database54.DAC_SYS_MEMORY, shouldn't it be database54.dbo.DAC_SYS_MEMORY

Comment: @siggemannen Getting same error even when I use 'database54.dbo.DAC_SYS_MEMORY'. Alternatively, we can add 'spring.datasource.database54.importer.SchemaPattern=dbo' in application.properties file (which I am using).